# Linux: How to find man page or different versions of Linux commands?

Tags: linux, manpage

I'm not sure what it's called exactly. But offen in a Linux 'man' page it refers to the same command but a different "version" number. For example:

```
$ man signal
```

Is SIGNAL(2), but there refers to a SIGNAL(5), for example. I tried this but it doesn't work on Linux CentOS 6:

```
$ man 5 signal
No entry for signal in section 5 of the manual
```

How do I find/access the man page for SIGNAL(5)? Thanks!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

Comment: You can use `apropos` command for checking which man pages contain or have something about the concept or command you are looking for. For example, try `apropos signal`

Comment: @Aeronth Yes, manpages (in this case) are a tool for developers - providing documentation.

Comment: Try googling `man 5 signal`. You may be surprised.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using it correctly in Linux. To get in what section a command exists, use `whatis`.

```
$ whatis printf
printf               (1)  - format and print data
printf               (3)  - formatted output conversion
```

The syntax for accessing the non-default manual section varies between different man implementations. On Solaris, for example, the syntax for reading printf(3) is:

```
man -s 3c printf
```

On Linux and BSD derivatives the same invocation would be:

```
man 3 printf
```

which searches for printf in section 3 of the man pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the numbers you can just run `man -a signal` and it will show you *all* signal manpages it knows about.